# How do I keep Empathy new message notifications after a disconnect?

Tags: 10.10, ubuntu-netbook, empathy, instant-messaging

When my internet connection goes down (which happens rather frequently here) and Empathy disconnects it drops notifications for new messages. So if I haven't opened the conversation window, I will probably never notice a message someone has sent me that I didn't catch in time. Is there a way for Empathy to remind you of new messages even after disconnects?

Comment: This question has not information added in it for a very long time and probably describes a bug in old package versions. I have flagged it to a moderator so it can be closed. If you think that this is still a valid question and that you are still suffering for this issue you can always flag it so that it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 0):

I assume this is rather a bug, meaning this is poor behaviour by empathy. Maybe you find a bug that is already filed on [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/empathy)